# How to create a diamond pattern with random fill colours and stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, illustration, patterns, illustrator-scripting

Pattern in question is the one on the left, it has random shades of black/grey, I'm not sure how to make something like this.

[image: Background]

Comment: sure, but what have you tried? since it's a large pattern covering a small area, it might not be worth the time to automate it.

Comment: Why do you assume it's a "pattern"? It could merely be a grid of squares which are individually filled with varying shades of grey.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's any automatic way (script) to generate that. A manual build should not take more than 5 minutes if you know your way around Illustrator:

- create a grid of squares stuck to each other
- apply white stroke
- apply white fills with different opacity level
- group and rotate by 45 degrees
- reduce opacity for the entire group to something under 10%
- adjust where needed
- use `Effect → Stylize → Feather` to blur the sides of the group (which probably needs to extend outside the artboard so you only get a blur on the right. not sure if they've introduced directional feather in Illustrator CC like InDesign has)